# No value returned in django powered HTML

Tags: django, dictionary, lookup

Looked for the solution for almost 2 days without luck - any guidance is much appreciated.

Given 'views.py' looks like this (all needed lib are imported properly):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404  
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.context_processors import request
from django.views import generic             
   
class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):   
    template_name = 'polls/djIndex.html'
    def test(request):
        data = {'temperature': '53F', 'state': 'NY', 'mood': ['good', 'bad']}
        return render(request, 'polls/djIndex.html',{'data':data})
```

***These are not working (no value returned) on djIndex.html:***

**test #1:**

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    <h3>{{key}}-----: {{value}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

**test #2:**

```
{% for key in data.items %}
   <p>Value of Key 1 : data["temperature"]</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**test #3**

```
{% for key, value in data %}
    <p>Key {{ key }}, Value {{ value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**test #4**

```
<h2> context2: {{data.temperature}}</h2>
```

***But these are working on djIndex.html:***

```
<h2> Temperature: {{temperature}}</h2>
<h2> State: {{state}}</h2>
<h2> Mood: {{mood}}</h2>
```

**Ask**: How to make those non-working test #1-#4 to work on my HTML page. **Especially test #3 and #4.** Am I doing something wrong in my Django config, as some of those test #1-#4 are accepted answers in some forums in different instances?

Answer (score 0):

To pass some context to the template from a class-based TemplateView you can override its [get_contecxt_data()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

Give this a try

```
class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):   
    template_name = 'polls/djIndex.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['temperature'] = '53F'
        context['state'] = 'NY'
        return context
```

Why didn't it work before

TemplatView or any other class-based views don't have a `test()` method to handle requests, so your test method wouldn't get called upon a request.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Sumithran. This is not what I am looking for. I already had these working (as I pointed out in 'These are working' section). I am more interested in ForLoop (1st priority) and anyting that references dictonary name in the variable.

Comment: Since you only have a single instance dict how can you iterate them with a for loop? that is not possible.

Comment: Goal is to iterate over keys of that single instance of dict and populate corresponding values. It should be possible, if I am not missing something here.